# Duplicating Rows in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to select all rows of table A and then duplicate all the rows in Table A while changing 1 field. Please find an example below along with the code I already wrote.

```
SELECT COLA, COLB, COLB
FROM TABLE A.
```

I want my end result to look like the following...

```
COLA     COLB     COLC
1234     test     01
1234     test     02
9876     testing  01
9876     testing  02
```

Comment: Format expected result. IDK what exactly do you want.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. What results are you getting now, and how do you want your results to be different?

Comment: Please describe the input data and tag the database engine you’re using since the answer may differ. What data is in the table and what is the changing field and how?

Comment: Are you talking about giving `RowNumber` to each duplicate? if so, using `ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY COLA,COLB ORDER BY COLA) as COLC` as part of your selected query

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
INSERT INTO A (COLA, COLB, COLC)
SELECT
    COLA, 'testing', COLC
FROM A
```

I assume that you wanted to change column B from 'test' to 'testing'. If COLA is your primary, autoincremented key than just put NULL instead of COLA in SELECT to avoid duplicated keys.